# Getting Error during Angular Production Build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, build, production

When I was preparing project to publish, I get this error. Can someone tell me how can i fix this?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js                                                   
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.                                           
    at getJSDocTags (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optim
er\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)                                                 
    at getFirstJSDocTag (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-o
imizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)                                             
    at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\b
ld-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13154:19)                                       
    at checkParenthesizedExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-de
it\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45628:56)                                 
    at checkExpressionWorker (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\bu
d-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45676:28)                                        
    at checkExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-op
mizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)                                              
    at checkBinaryLikeExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devki
build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)                                    
    at checkBinaryExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\bu
d-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45147:20)                                        
    at checkExpressionWorker (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\bu
d-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45702:28)                                        
    at checkExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-op
mizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)                                              
    at checkExpressionCached (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\bu
d-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)                                        
    at getTypeOfExpression (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\buil
optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45577:28)                                          
    at checkDeclarationInitializer (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angular-dev
t\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45469:24)                                  
    at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@angul
-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30738:28)                            
    at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules
angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30961:24)                     
    at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (D:\Visual Studio\asp.net\mean_blog\client\node_modules\@
gular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31062:28)                       
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                               
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                       
npm ERR! blog@0.0.0 build: `cd client && ng build --prod && cd .. && node ./bin/www`                   
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                 
npm ERR!                                                                                               
npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.0.0 build script.                                                        
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.     

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                   
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yashdeep Raj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-06T19_43_30_221Z-debug.log
```

I have fixed some error, but these are about module and I know nothing about these error.

Comment: try with upgrading your package : ```npm install @auth0/angular-jwt```

Comment: @fatemefazli i get these warning during npm install  npm WARN angular2-flash-messages@2.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-flash-messages@2.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http

Comment: did you try my command?

Comment: @fatemefazli yes, I tried and get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue using `@auth0/angular-jwt` with angular 6. You first need to uninstall angular2-jwt completely:

```
npm uninstall angular2-jwt --save
```

Then you can run:

```
npm install @auth0/angular-jwt
```

Only these two command lines helped me. All the best.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the issue, actually I was using the angular2-jwt(Deprecated) along with @auth0/angular-jwt. Which was causing issue. So I uninstalled the angular2-jwt update code with @auth0/angular-jwt and Everything start working fine.

Comment: please add clear description...that help us to find root cause and solution